# The title doesn't update when changed using the mouse

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, title, inline-editor

When I edit the title with the mouse, it doesn't change:

Alternative spelt wrong:

> [image]

Alternative spelt right in editor (I right clicked to change it with spell check) but it doesn't update:

> [image]

Here I deleted the word (with backspace - it updated) then pasted it back in, and it didn't update:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is going out with build rev `2014.1.12.2812` on meta and `2014.12.1.2056` on sites.